# Can relative velocity of a particle exceed the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, faster-than-light

Consider two particles (having same mass) moving with constant velocity very close to speed of light, say $0.99c$ in opposite directions. Will the magnitude of their relative velocities exceed the speed of light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they will not exceed the speed of light. Because the relative speed formula for any particle with a rest mass goes:

$$v_\text{rel} = \frac{v_1 - v_2}{1 - \frac{v_1v_2}{c^2}}$$

If you use 0.99c and -0.99c you will see that their relative speeds wont exceed the speed of light.